# Java equivalent of PHP code return different base 64 encoding result

Tags: java, php, base64

Java Code

```
completeStrBytes = new byte[2];
completeStrBytes[0] = (byte)(signatureLength>>>8); //signatureLength = 128
completeStrBytes[1] = (byte)signatureLength;
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(completeStrBytes));
```

output: AIA=

PHP Code

```
$firstPart = $signatureLength >> 8;
$secondPart = $signatureLength;
var_dump(base64_encode($firstPart . $secondPart));
```

output: string(8) "MDEyOA=="

I understand PHP string already treat as byte string.

May I know how to get java equivalent code in PHP? what's wrong in the PHP code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the case of Java you're calculating base64 for 2-byte array `{ 0x00, 0x80 }` . In case of php you're calculation base64 for a 4-character string `"0128"` (which you got when concatenated two numbers as strings).

You probably want to [convert those numbers to chars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) first:

```
  var_dump(base64_encode(chr($firstPart) . chr($secondPart))); // string(4) "AIA="
```

**UPD**

You also may want to use function [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to convert different data types into a string:

```
<?php
  $signatureLength = 128;
  var_dump(base64_encode(pack('n', $signatureLength))); // string(4) "AIA="
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also a `base64url` encoding, which is NOT the `base64_encode()` from PHP.

When you use PHP `base64_encode()` for example for JWT encoding/decoding, you will get into trouble.

So for your case try

```
var_dump(base64url_encode($firstPart . $secondPart));
```

```
function base64url_encode($data)
{
    $b64 = base64_encode($data);
    if ($b64 === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $url = strtr($b64, '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($url, '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data, $strict = false)
{
    $b64 = strtr($data, '-_', '+/');
    return base64_decode($b64, $strict);
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh That's why I've provided that functions. There aren't.